# Aggregating DataFrame leaves me with just the aggregated column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in python, which I want to perform a simply aggregation on.  My df looks like:

df:

| City | Sex | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | Male | 20 |
| London | Female | 30 |
| London | Male | 25 |
| London | Female | 22 |
| London | Male | 33 |
| London | Female | 45 |

I want to return a dataframe still with 3 columns but the minimum age, so the result I'm looking for would be:

| City | Sex | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | Male | 20 |
| London | Female | 22 |

I've used:

```
df = df.groupby(['City', 'Sex']).min()
```

but this just returns a df of:

| Age |
| --- |
| 20 |
| 22 |

How do I keep the group by columns in the revised dataframe?  I see the concatenated columns as the index but the df.info is just the one column, as it also is if I output it to excel.

Thanks